# Creating Chrome Extension to Dismiss Notifications via Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, shortcut

I'm new to Chrome extension development. I am currently looking to make a Chrome extension to dismiss notifications. I want the extension to be activated once via shortcut keys.

Before looking at the code below, I want to let it be known that the `alert` does show up... but the Chrome Extensions page shows the error:

> "Error in event handler for commands.onCommand: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined"

on the line:

```
chrome.notifications.getAll((items) => {
```

The `chrome.notifications` object is somehow undefined, so it seems that Chrome thinks that there are no current notifications being displayed...which is strange because there indeed are, as the image shows.

Would anyone please help by shedding some light on this situation?

---

```
manifest.json:
{
"name": "ClearAll",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Clear notifications!",
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},

"commands": {
  "clear": {
    "suggested_key":{
      "default": "Alt+Shift+S" 
    },
    "description": "Executes clear"
 }
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

---

background.js:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if (command == 'clear') {
      alert("testing");
      chrome.notifications.getAll((items) => {
        if (items) 
          for (let key in items) 
            chrome.notifications.clear(key);
      });
    }
});
```

---

Error:

[image: Image: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined error]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the `notifications` permission to your manifest

```
{
    "name": "ClearAll",
    "permissions": ["notifications"],
    .......
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right, thank you for that!

After adding that line, I no longer get the error...but the notification actually never gets dismissed! I've gone into chrome://flags to test the script on both native and non-native notification toasts, but I'm still having no luck.

Do you have any idea as to why that might be?

Comment: This wouldn't actually help because the "notifications" permission only lets you create/edit/clear your extension's notifications, not system-wide notifications, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might already have figured this out, but for anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future: it's not possible to write an extension that dismisses *all* notifications on Chrome because it is not possible for any extension to get access to a user's browser-wide notifications; the `notifications` permission in the `manifest.json` lets you create and clear notifications created by *your* extension. Indeed, it would be a privacy violation if any extension was allowed to do this!

From https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-getAll,

> Retrieves all the notifications of **this** app or extension (emphasis mine.)